# detection of sqlite3 transaction

Tags: c, sqlite, locking

When I begin a transaction on a sqlite3 base and insert something. Naturally, there will be a lock on it and an according journal file. At the same time, there maybe another C programme which runs some sqlite pragma integrity_check, but not on the "in transaction" ones.

I **want to detect the transaction** before doing anything. But I didn't make it. There do has something `inTransaction` in the source code of the sqlite3, but unfortunately it's in an opaque structure....

So, please help me T_T

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your problem, correct me if i'm wrong. Do you want to know if the database is locked?

I use SQLite in python, so maybe in C you can do something more sophisticated. I think SQLite returns `SQL_BUSY` when is locked. You can define your own handler for this situation.

Check out [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html), and maybe [this one](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html).

You can try to perform your operation and retry or do whatever you want if you get `SQL_BUSY`.

Comment: You're welcome, maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153091/sqlite-check-reader-writer-lock) you can find a better answer though is also related to db locking.