# How can I tell if a SQLIte update/transaction was prevented due to database being locked by another write?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Like the title says, my SQLite query is below. I am using c# and writing an application. I need to know if the query below was prevented from writing to the database due to the database being locked by another write. Since I understand SQLite only allows one write at a time. Do the others just fail? Or do they get queued or something and wait for the lock to be removed and then begin?

```
using (var cmd = SQLite_Connection.CreateCommand())
using (var SQLite_Transaction= SQLite_Connection.BeginTransaction())
cmd.CommandText = UPDATE testDb.testTable SET testAge= 5 WHERE testName = Joseph
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SQLite_Transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite: check reader/writer lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153091/sqlite-check-reader-writer-lock)

Comment: That duplicate link was for c++ and python, links to sqlite doco pages that are language agnostic and those that arnt also link to multiple language examples